# Pdflatex not compiling when a separate section file is not included

Tags: bibtex, compiling, input

I'm working on a multi-section document, where each section is written in a separate .tex file. The main file contains the following code snippet:

```
\input{introduction}
\input{genrate}
\input{setup}
\input{conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,ToA5bib}
```

Pdflatex (and bibtex) does its job as intended.

However, when **\input{setup}** is not present, I have some problems. If I delete the .aux and .bbl files, the new file compiles once, but after running bibtex, the next run of pdflatex turns into something looking like an endless loop, without any results. Putting it back, everything's fine again

The **setup.tex** file does not contain anything bar a section start, some text and an align environment. Not even a citation. What could be the problem?

*Edit: Here's a compilable version.*

**main file**

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{microtype}  %Getting rid of underfull hboxes
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{pslatex}
\usepackage{collcell,array}

\usepackage{flushend}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,angles,quotes}

% Expectation value operator
\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb{E}}

% Matrix
\newcommand{\matr}[1]{\bm{#1}}

% Ceiling function
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\ceil}{\lceil}{\rceil}

% The number `e'
\providecommand*{\eu}%
{\ensuremath{\mathrm{e}}}

% The imaginary unit `i'
\providecommand*{\iu}%
{\ensuremath{\mathrm{i}}}

% argmax and argmin
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}

% Big O notation
\newcommand{\bigO}{\mathcal{O}}


% Red flag for missing parts
\providecommand*{\MISS}
{\textcolor{red}{MISSING }}

% New cell type
\newcommand{\shiftdown}[1]{\smash{\raisebox{-.6\normalbaselineskip}{#1}}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\shiftdown}r<{\endcollectcell}}

% Multiple references setting
%\usepackage[square,sort&compress,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}

% Fixing IEEEtran.cls bibliography errors
\makeatletter
\def\endthebibliography{%
  \def\@noitemerr{\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist
}
\makeatother

% No page numbering
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\title{Title}
\author{xyz}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\begin{abstract}

\end{abstract}

\begin{IEEEkeywords}

\end{IEEEkeywords}

\input{introduction}
%\input{genrate}
%\input{setup}
\input{conclusion}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,ToA5bib}
%\vspace{-30pt}
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{fig/schranzbw}}]{...} 
\end{IEEEbiography}
%\vspace{-30pt}
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{fig/udvarybw}}]{...} (...) 
\end{IEEEbiography}

\end{document}
```

**setup.tex**

```
\section{Experimental Setup}

test
```

The other files may include anything (section start and some non-empty text), the behaviour remains. However, excluding ANY OTHER input file along **setup.tex** results in perfect behaviour.

*Edit 2:*

However strange, but it seems that the problem is caused by the \align environments in genrate.tex. When changed to \equation, everything is fine (apart from the alignment, obviously).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without having a compilable document to reproduce your described behavior, it's almost impossible to tell where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you, I added as much as I can.

Comment: Still does not compile (we don't have `introduction.tex`, `conclusion.tex`, the `bib` files nor the figures). Commenting out all missing elements, compilation works for me. What is your error exactly, what does the compiler say?

Comment: The compiler says nothing. It just keeps on running in the background without producing anything. I have problems sharing some of the files because of the content is not public at this moment, but I'll try to do my best.

Comment: The fact that your real document has private information should not matter, make a copy and just have the text of each section be `hello` or some such. Similarly delete every `\usepackage` line that you can delete while still showing the problem.  No document written this century should be using the `epsfig` or `pslatex` packages

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, thanks, I'm on it. \input is not referencing a nonexistent file, the problem is simply with not including the \input command in my main document. Thank you also for the package suggestions.

Comment: actually I misread your question, so i deleted that first comment, but still it is impossible to see the issue with the question as it is currently posted (and please remove pslatex and epsfig from your real document, I wrote both of them and they were both written to emulate systems that were obsolete in 1993, seeing them appear now, in 2019 is very weird:-)

Comment: I now see that the problem ceases to exist when replacing all other sections with "hello".

Comment: so the problem is in code you have not shown, if you make an example that shows the problem, someone will be able to help, otherwise we can not really say anything.

Comment: I figured it has something to do with the bibliography. I appreciate your help, but I did not yet find a way to show a "working" example without removing the private text. I think I'll take the time to get into it in detail.

Comment: A now-deleted comment said that the problem went away when you changed an `align` in `genrate` to `equation`.  So that's where you need to look.  Please create a minimum example with just that `align` content, only as much as needed to trigger the error.  If we can see exactly what the error message is, and the input that is causing it, it's much easier to get to the bottom of this.